# Is there a temporary, anonymous object involved in creating maps in Go?

Tags: c++, go, constructor, temporary-objects, anonymous-objects

I'm newly learning Go after primarily developing in C/C++ for a long time. So I still have a proclivity to analogize Go syntax to C/C++.

My Go tutor (ChatGPT **:(** ) told me that this is how you create + initialize a map (from string to int) in Go:

```
var foo = map[string]int{}
```

or

```
var foo = make(map[string]int)
```

To my C/C++-biased eyes, the use of the `=` looks like default-initialized variable `foo` is being assigned from a temporary, anonymous object of type `map[string]int`.
(ChatGPT hasn't explained `make()` to my satisfaction, but it still "looks like" there's implicitly a temporary, anonymous object involved because of a presumed object returned by `make()` assigned to `foo` with `=`)

My questions are:
Do the two statements above involve assignment from temporary, anonymous objects?
If yes, (how) can you instantiate (and default-initialize) a `map` object in Go without involving any temporary, anonymous objects?

What I've tried:
Neither of the following appear to be valid in Go:

```
var foo map[string]int
```

```
var foo map[string]int{}
```

I'm analogizing this Go syntax to the C++ "equivalent" of

```
std::map<string, int> foo;
```

vs.

```
std::map<string, int> foo = map<string, int>();
```

Comment: Remember that Chat GPT is a language model, not a true AI, and the language it's modelling is not Go. I wouldn't trust Chat GPT any further than I could, uh, throw it.

Comment: Instead of using ChatGPT, buy and read https://www.gopl.io. It's a much better tutor and will teach you things which are *actually* correct, rather than *incidentally* correct.

Comment: The C++ code doesn't make use of any assignment. It also doesn't create any temporary object (guaranteed since C++17, optionally before). Also that's _value-initialization_, not _default-initialization_.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `var foo map[string]int` is not valid? It's not very *useful* (you can't do anything with a map variable that holds nil except assign to it, compare it to nil, and get its len which is 0), but it's 100% legal.

Answer (score 1):

`var x = y` (or `x := y`) is how you declare a variable and initialize it with a value in Go. The alternate syntax you're looking for does not exist, and there is no "temporary variable" created here.

Looking for analogs to C++ is not useful. A map is not a C++ class. It is "copied" by reference.

Even if you run the following code...

```
var m1 = map[string]int{}
var m2 = m1
```

...you're *still* not copying anything.